# Incompatible shapes for Accuracy when fitting tensorflow2 model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am running a text generation model (RNN) on  Tensorfow 2.0.0-alpha0 and even though I get the loss metric when fitting the model, I get the following error when inserting accuracy:

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [64,200]
>   [[{{node metrics_4/accuracy/Equal}}]]
>   [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6491]

I tried to manually define accuracy on a single batch (pre-training):

```
def loss(labels, logits):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=True)
def accuracy(labels, logits):
    return tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(labels,l ogits)

example_batch_loss  = loss(target_example_batch, example_batch_predictions)
example_batch_acc  = accuracy(target_example_batch, example_batch_predictions)
print("Prediction shape: ", example_batch_predictions.shape, " # (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")
print("Loss:      ", example_batch_loss.numpy().mean())
print("Accuracy:      ", example_batch_acc.numpy().mean())
```

The output was:

> Prediction shape:  (64, 200, 34)  # (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)
>   Loss:       3.5263805
>   Accuracy:       0.01265625

Then I followed with:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr) 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics =['accuracy']) 
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks[checkpoint_callback])
```

and got the error mentioned above (loss works fine).  If I try "accuracy = accuracy" within compile, I get:

> raise ValueError('Session keyword arguments are not support during
>   eager execution. You passed: %s' % (kwargs,))

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accuracy` isn't a standard argument of `Model.fit` - it will be accepted under `**kwargs` which will then be passed to `session.run` in graph mode. Try `metrics=[accuracy]`.